# Unexpected iOS Safari behaviour when dynamically updating viewport meta with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, orientation, mobile-safari

I am adapting a website for iPhone iOS Safari browser. As I wish to make content takes whole viewport on both device orientations, I am making dynamic update of the `meta[name='viewport']` tag.

Here's what I have set by default inside `meta[name='viewport']`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.51, minimum-scale=0.51, maximum-scale=0.51" />
```

Then, right after page is loaded, I am executing the following JavaScript code to make sure the entire viewport is occupied with the website and centered:

```
var viewport = $("html head meta[name='viewport']");

function switchViewport() {
    var wider = "0.765",
        shorter = "0.51";

    switch (window.orientation) {  
        case 0:  
        case 180:
            viewport.attr("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=" + wider + ", minimum-scale=" + wider + ", maximum-scale=" + wider + "");
        break; 

        case -90:  
        case 90:  
            viewport.attr("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=" + shorter + ", minimum-scale=" + shorter + ", maximum-scale=" + shorter + "");
        break;
    }
}

$(window).on("orientationchange", switchViewport);

switchViewport();
```

When I test on real iPhone (4, 4S) **trying to rotate the device so 'onorientationchange' even is fired, it does exactly what I wished with a code above, except first turn**.
When I make first device rotation to change orientation, it doesn't render as I planned. However, when turning more times, it goes to normal. Just the first turn fails because of something.

Here's a website: http://goo.gl/VXyBg I am working on, so you can directly test with you real iPhone or just simulator. Better real one, as simulator doesn't give the same results comparing to real device for this special situation.

If anyone faces similar situation or have knowledge, experience on where the problem could be, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Working well on iPhone 5. No issue.

Comment: @closure, tried to load in landscape orientation, than turning to portrait? Haven't faced something like this when making a first rotation from landscape to portrait: http://d.pr/i/KUo7 ?

Comment: saw it now. I was not using the site with new.*.com

Comment: BTW, the site www.*.com works properly.

Comment: @closure, sorry I am relating to new.*.com, mentioned in question description above: http://goo.gl/VXyBg

Comment: Tried seeing the code you have posted via chrome browser on mac. I am not able to find the code. It is not in ml.js or in the html. Do you render different code based on device?

Comment: @closure, yes, for iPhone I render this JS file: http://goo.gl/RfvxX. However, code is described in a question above.

Comment: Just a suggestion, could you please try after wrapping the iphone.js code in $(document).ready().